# How to use Omu.ValueInjecter Asp.net Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, viewmodel, valueinjecter

First I retrieve a list of AtdChannels of type IEnumerable:

```
IEnumerable DataSource = _context.AtdChannels.Where(x => x.AtdId == AtdId);
```

Secondly I create an empty IEnumerable of type atdChannelSummaryList:

```
IEnumerable<atdChannelSummaryList> atdChannel= Enumerable.Empty<atdChannelSummaryList>();
```

And I tried to inject values from DataSource to atdChannel:

```
atdChannel.InjectFrom<FlatLoopValueInjection>(DataSource )
```

But I dont succeed. How can I make it happen?

Comment: you need to call InjectFrom inside a loop on each element of the source and call .Add(newItem) on the target